# Passing argument from a DialogFragment to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am running into an issue where I would like to pass a `Set` from a `DialogFragment` back to the `Fragment` that calls it initially.

I have tried implementing an interface but I cannot seem to get it to work properly from the Fragment.

**Is there another way to arguments from a `DialogFragment` >> `Fragment`? Or would I need to implement the interface on the `Activity`, and then move it from there?**

The issue seems to be a `NullPointerException`, and I am pretty sure it is because the interface needs to be implemented on the Activity level, and not on the Fragment. The crash occurs when hitting the "Positive Button" for the dialog.

**DIALOGFRAGMENT**

```
public class CustomPermissionDialog extends DialogFragment implements
    OnCheckedChangeListener {

String _permission;
View convertView;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
Switch alertDelete;
Set<String> permSet = new TreeSet<String>();

public static interface OnCompleteDialogInterface {
    public abstract void OnCompleteDialog(Set mPermSet);
}

private OnCompleteDialogInterface mInterface;

public CustomPermissionDialog(Context context, String permissionName) {

    _permission = permissionName;
    mInterface = (OnCompleteDialogInterface) getActivity();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    if (_permission == "Alerts") {
        convertView = (View) inflater
                .inflate(
                        getResources().getLayout(
                                R.layout.alerts_perm_dialog), null);
        alertDelete = (Switch) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.switchAlertDelete);
        alertDelete.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    }
    if (_permission == "Automation") {
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(
                getResources().getLayout(R.layout.automation_perm_dialog),
                null);

    }
    if (_permission == "Books") {
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(
                getResources().getLayout(R.layout.books_perm_dialog), null);

    }

    if (_permission == "Codes") {
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(
                getResources().getLayout(R.layout.codes_perm_dialog), null);

    }

    if (_permission == "DBS") {
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(
                getResources().getLayout(R.layout.dbs_perm_dialog), null);

    }
    if (_permission == "Feedback") {
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(
                getResources().getLayout(R.layout.feedback_perm_dialog),
                null);

    }

    if (_permission == "Groups") {
        convertView = (View) inflater
                .inflate(
                        getResources().getLayout(
                                R.layout.groups_perm_dialog), null);

    }

    if (_permission == "Inventory") {
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(
                getResources().getLayout(R.layout.inventory_perm_dialog),
                null);

    }

    if (_permission == "Jobs") {
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(
                getResources().getLayout(R.layout.jobs_perm_dialog), null);

    }

    if (_permission == "Locations") {
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(
                getResources().getLayout(R.layout.locations_perm_dialog),
                null);

    }

    if (_permission == "Logs") {
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(
                getResources().getLayout(R.layout.logs_perm_dialog), null);

    }

    if (_permission == "Messages") {
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(
                getResources().getLayout(R.layout.messages_perm_dialog),
                null);

    }

    if (_permission == "Services") {
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(
                getResources().getLayout(R.layout.services_perm_dialog),
                null);

    }
    if (_permission == "Settings") {
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(
                getResources().getLayout(R.layout.settings_perm_dialog),
                null);

    }
    if (_permission == "Templates") {
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(
                getResources().getLayout(R.layout.templates_perm_dialog),
                null);

    }
    if (_permission == "Tools") {
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(
                getResources().getLayout(R.layout.tools_perm_dialog), null);

    }
    if (_permission == "Updates") {
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(
                getResources().getLayout(R.layout.updates_perm_dialog),
                null);

    }
    if (_permission == "Users") {
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(
                getResources().getLayout(R.layout.users_perm_dialog), null);

    }

    // defining the alertdialog
    builder.setTitle(_permission + " Permissions");

    builder.setView(convertView);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.accept,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // do something with the new note
                    mInterface.OnCompleteDialog(permSet);

                }
            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (alertDelete.isChecked()) {
        // The toggle is enabled
        permSet.add("alert_delete");
        Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "CHECKED");
    } else {
        // The toggle is disabled
        permSet.remove("alert_delete");
        Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "UNCHECKED");
    }

}

}
```

**INSIDE THE FRAGMENT**

```
    @Override
public void OnCompleteDialog(Set mPermSet) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.permSet = mPermSet;
    String tempPermString = permSet.toString();
    Log.e("PERMISSIONS", tempPermString);

}
```

**STACKTRACE**

```
    10-30 11:41:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(16925): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 11:41:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(16925): Process: com.e.main, PID: 16925
10-30 11:41:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(16925): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-30 11:41:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(16925):    at com.e.dialog.CustomPermissionDialog$1.onClick(CustomPermissionDialog.java:171)
10-30 11:41:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(16925):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
10-30 11:41:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(16925):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-30 11:41:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(16925):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-30 11:41:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(16925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
10-30 11:41:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(16925):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 11:41:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(16925):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-30 11:41:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(16925):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
10-30 11:41:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(16925):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
```

Comment: Did you consider using an Application class?

Comment: I did not. I have one created, but I am not sure what steps to take to make it do what I need it to?

Comment: Store the information you want in a global var when you get back  to the fragment you can retrieve the data from that var

Comment: @MedAL -You can simply call setArguments(bundle) on the fragment with a bundle containing his _permission String argument.

Answer (score 1):

Your null pointer is due to trying to set `mInterface` in the constructor of your `DialogFragment` using `getActivity()`. `getActivity()` at this point in the fragment's lifecycle is null.

Try setting it in `onCreate` or just cast the activity as the interface when you call it (assuming your activity is guaranteed to implement your interface)

```
((OnCompleteDialogInterface) getActivity()).OnCompleteDialog(permSet);
```

Another issue is that your string comparisons are all wrong. You should be using

```
if (_permission.equals("whatever"))
```

Second you should be using if/else statements to check your `_permission` string to avoid unnecessary checks.

Additionally, fragment's should have empty constructors. You should look how to pass your `_permissions` string using the `.setArgument(bundle)` method for fragments

Your layout inflation is a bit over-complicated

Instead of

```
 convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(getResources().getLayout(R.layout.jobs_perm_dialog), null);
```

You can just be using

```
 convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.jobs_perm_dialog, null);
```

Comment: I changed a lot of my code. Thank you for the tips, and good practices.

Answer (score 0):

Your dialog doesn't have an activity yet in the constructor, so calling `getActivity()` there will return null. Move the initialization of `mInterface` to `onCreateDialog()`.